# #endif without #if

Tags: arduino-ide

I have an extrange Problem...
I have written this short code:

```
////////////// BOARD SETTINGS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\
#define BAUD_RATE 9600

// Board type selection
// Uncomment the wanted
//#define WAND 0
//#define GUN 0
#define RIFLE 0


////////////// WAND SETTINGS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\
#ifdef WAND
//#define USE_CHARGER 0

#endif

////////////// GUN SETTINGS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\
#if GUN
//#define USE_CHARGER 0

#endif

////////////// RIFLE SETTINGS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\
#ifdef RIFLE
  #define USE_CHARGER 0

#endif
```

It's in a file called `Settings.h`, that I use in the main code:

```
#include "Settings.h"

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  #ifdef WAND
    Serial.println("Initializing Wand...");
  #endif
  #ifdef GUN
    Serial.println("Initializing Gun...");
  #endif
  #ifdef RIFLE
    Serial.println("Initializing Rifle...");
  #endif
}

void loop(){
  #ifdef WAND

  #endif
  #ifdef GUN

  #endif
  #ifdef RIFLE

  #endif
}
```

But for an extrange reason, it gives me this error: `error: #endif without #if`
Full error is:

```
In file included from D:\MEGA\Winsoft\Projects\Hardware\MWands\Arduino_5\Arduino_5.ino:1:0:

Settings.h:15: error: #endif without #if

 #endif

  ^

Settings.h:21: error: #endif without #if

 #endif

  ^

Settings.h:27: error: #endif without #if

 #endif

  ^

exit status 1
#endif without #if
```

Any idea in where am I wrong?

And taking advantage that I'm asking, is necessary the 0 after `#define RIFLE 0`, next to each definition?

Comment: The way you are using it, no you dont' have to add the 0 `#define XYZ` is enough. `#ifdef XYZ` will work for this case.

Comment: Also, you have declared `#if GUN` which you probably meant `#ifdef GUN`.

Comment: Using `#ifdef` and ending with `#endif` still showing me that error

Comment: I didn't say it would fix the error, I was just answering your second question "is it necessary to have the 0..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your comment style is causing the problem.

Remove the `////////////// BOARD SETTINGS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\` style comments, or change them to something like: `/*----------- BOARD SETTINGS -----------*/`

Comment: The \ at the end of the comment continues the current line onto the next one, so you get `///// comment \\\\\#ifdef...` which comments out the `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove backslashes at the end of comments on lines before `#ifdefs`, it will work just fine.

The gvim editor was much more helpful in that:
[image]